# Where can I get Stack Overflow wallpapers?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I want a Stack Overflow wallpaper to be set as my desktop background. Is there a collection of Stack Overflow wallpapers?

It looks like a good way to show the interest to people in answering questions on Stack Overflow.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The only correct SO wallpaper is an Active Desktop one pointing on the site, and refreshing questions every 15 seconds.

Comment: The instant Unicornify can render larger images than 128x128, I'll build *beautiful* Unicorn wallpapers. http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/187606

Comment: @Pekka: For the Chief Marketing Officer you have been for the unicorns, I'd even make you a large one :)

Comment: @balpha Great! :) For a wallpaper, I'd need a unicorn that is completely in view (no clipping). A clipped rainbow or horizon I can clone. An unclipped view of the topmost one in your twitter background picture http://a1.twimg.com/profile_background_images/72729688/twitbg.png would be great.

Comment: Anyone know what caused this question to return a blank page?

Comment: @Gnoupi: Now that's an awesome idea. With a simple script you could create a static wallpaper which reflects information, like the current reputation...I think I'll try to write such a thing.

Comment: @Gnoupi the correct refresh time is 90 seconds - anything less over time will get you in trouble with Jeff and the main page is cached for that long anyway.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Unicornified Wallpapers!**

With a high-res Unicorn courtesy of course of @balpha and his marvellous [**Unicorn Farm.**](http://unicornify.appspot.com/)

[image]
**Unicorn en route from Iceland to Basle, Switzerland, above the black forest**

[1920x1200](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/4_1920_1200.png) - [1920x1080](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/4_1920_1080.png) - [1680x1050](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/4_1680_1050.png) - [1600x1200](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/4_1600_1200.png) - [1280x1024](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/4_1280_1024.png) - [1280x800](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/4_1280_800.png) - [1024x768](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/4_1024_768.png)

[image]
**Unicorn riding the green plains, with Rainbow**

[1920x1200](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/1_1920_1200.png) - [1920x1080](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/1_1920_1080.png) - [1680x1050](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/1_1680_1050.png) - [1600x1200](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/1_1600_1200.png) - [1280x1024](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/1_1280_1024.png) - [1280x800](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/1_1280_800.png) - [1024x768](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/1_1024_768.png)

[image]
**Unicorn on white canvas**

[1920x1200](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/2_1920_1200.png) - [1920x1080](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/2_1920_1080.png) - [1680x1050](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/2_1680_1050.png) - [1600x1200](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/2_1600_1200.png) - [1280x1024](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/2_1280_1024.png) - [1280x800](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/2_1280_800.png) - [1024x768](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/2_1024_768.png)

[image]
**Unicorn riding the plains**

[1920x1200](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/3_1920_1200.png) - [1920x1080](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/3_1920_1080.png) - [1680x1050](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/3_1680_1050.png) - [1600x1200](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/3_1600_1200.png) - [1280x1024](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/3_1280_1024.png) - [1280x800](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/3_1280_800.png) - [1024x768](http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/3_1024_768.png)

I'm releasing the images under the same license that applies to this answer - i.e. [Creative Commons by-sa](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/).

Comment: Those are magnificent.

Comment: What? No 1920 x 1200 love?

Comment: If these were `1680x1050` they would be on my desktop SO FAST

Comment: @SeanJA your wish is my command. `1920x1200` done.

Comment: @Phoshi `1680x1050` done.

Comment: Awesome; thanks for the 1920x1200s.  Any chance of getting some with other unicorns on them?  Three monitors with the same unicorn is a bit boring :-P.

Comment: @James I'll ask balpha for some more Unicorns, but it may take a while until I get around to it. I'll post updates here.

Comment: This is a version 4 unicorn anyway (note that the legs are somewhat static); the newer ones look a lot more dynamic.

Comment: @balpha great stuff! Can you send me a few specimens when you get around to it? No hurry though.

Answer (score 28):

You minimize your browser window?

Comment: I agree... I don't see how wallpapers are useful at all

Comment: This answer is not useful. (Comment instead ; )

Comment: Wallpapers are very useful. I've just renamed http://www.pekkagaiser.com/stuff/unicorns/1.png as c:\windows\bliss.bmp on everyone elses pc where I had access...

Comment: @gre that is the best idea evar!!!1!!111

Comment: @gre you need to use one of the full resolution versions, though, of course.

Answer (score 24):

Here is one for you:
[image: SO wallpaper]

Comment: you misspelled "handsome"

Comment: Not according to my dictionary, @Jeff: http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=on&chinese=both&pinyin=diacritic&search=h%E4%DFlich&relink=on